# Why is my component not reacting to the changes? Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have a child component that takes in some props to decide for a state:

```
  export interface IProps {
    selected?: boolean,
    answered?: boolean
  }
  const {selected, answered} = defineProps<IProps>()
```

Depending on answered / selected different styles need to be applied. I tried this using computed function:

```
//  in template
  <div :class="cardClasses" />

// in setup script
  const classes = {
    base: "w-40 h-20 m-0 rounded-xl drop-shadow-lg flex justify-center items-center text-white text-shadow",
    default: "bg-primary hover:bg-primary/70 hover:ring-2 hover:ring-primary hover:ring-inset cursor-pointer",
    selected: "bg-primary/70 ring-teal-900 ring-2 ring-inset cursor-pointer",
    done: "bg-primary/40"
  }

  const status = computed(() => {
    if(answered) return "done"
    if(selected) return "selected"
    return "default"
  })
  const cardClasses = computed(() => `${classes.base} ${classes[status.value]}`)
```

The initial value for status is always 'default' but after clicking the child component it should turn to 'selected'.

The state is hold by the parent component but I checked the value change for selected in the onUpdated:

```
  onUpdated(() => {
    console.log("updated")
    console.log(selected, status)
  })
```

selected changed to true but status is still on 'default'.

How to I make this reactive?

Comment: Paste full code of your components so every can understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructing the props makes them loose the reactivity, you should wrap them by [`toRefs`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs) then destruct them :

```js
import {toRefs} from 'vue'

 export interface IProps {
    selected?: boolean,
    answered?: boolean
  }
  const props=defineProps<IProps>()

  const {selected, answered} = toRefs(props)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that works. I realized I had this almost before. I had .. toRefs( defineProps<IProps>()).. but this gave me an "ReferenceError: defineProps is not defined" - although I imported it. Do you know why by any chance?

Comment: you're welcome, I think that defining it directly as argument prevents the compiler to identify the component props